# mapping http response to object array in type argument

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

I wonder if someone can explain this error to me, since Im relatively new to angular, typescript and rxjs.

What I try to do is to map the server response I get for calling `getHeroes()` in a format that makes it easy for my components to consume it.

This is my `getHeroes()` method that is working:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    const heroes = this.http.get<any>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((res: EmbeddedResponse) => res._embedded.heroes),
        tap(data => this.log('HeroService: fetched Heroes'),
          catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
        ))
    return heroes
  }
```

*Notice the **any** type argument in `this.http.get<any>()`*

I would like to be more specific with the type argument in `getHeroes()`:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    const heroes = this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((res: EmbeddedResponse) => res._embedded.heroes),
        tap(data => this.log('HeroService: fetched Heroes'),
          catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
        ))
    return heroes
  }
```

*Notice the **Hero[]** type argument in `this.http.get<Hero[]>()`*

But changing the type argument in `getHeroes()` from **any -> Hero[]** resolves in this Error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<EmbeddedResponse, Hero[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Hero[], Hero[]>'.
  Property '_embedded' is missing in type 'Hero[]' but required in type 'EmbeddedResponse'.
```

The EmbeddedResponse interface looks like this:

```
interface EmbeddedResponse {
  _embedded: {
    heroes: Hero[]
  }
}
```

The response from the server looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "heroes" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Dicke Berta",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes/1"
        },
        "hero" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 5,
      "name" : "Cobra-Car",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes/5"
        },
        "hero" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes/5"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/heroes"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/heroes/search"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type you defined in get is only assigned to the get function itself, not the whole chain. You defined get to return type Hero[], but in map you expect it to be of type EmbeddedResponse. Instead define get to return EmbeddedResponse:

```
this.http.get<EmbeddedResponse>(this.heroesUrl)
```

Then you don´t even need to define the type for "res" in map, since that is then already defined (though you can also leave it for readability):

```
map((res) => res._embedded.heroes)
```

The return type of your chain is defined by the last element return something, in your case map. res._embedded.heroes is of type Hero[], therefore your const heroes will be of type Observable<Hero[]>.

Finally in tap and catchError you probably set your brackets wrong. catchError shouldn´t be a part of tap but rather chained after it:

```
   tap(data => this.log('HeroService: fetched Heroes')),
   catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But isnt ```map((res: EmbeddedResponse) => res._embedded.heroes)``` supposed to return ```Hero[]```

Comment: @Vultimitavin It is, but you define that in map and not in the previous get call. You could also do this: `map<Hero[]>((res) => res._embedded.heroes)`

Comment: Then I dont get it... Maybe you could clarify when I tell you my understanding:
1. ```this.http.get<typeargument>()``` The *typeargument* defines what I expect to get back from the ```http.get()```
2. ```map((res: EmbeddedResponse) => res._embedded.heroes)``` returns an object array of type ```Hero``` and ultimatively hands it over to ```http.get()```
3. In my understanding I would now be fine setting ```Hero[]``` as my type argument -> ```this.http.get<Hero[]>()``` but this is obviously not the right understanding

Comment: @Vultimitavin You´re wrong in your second point: The return of `map` does not get handed over to `get` but rather is chained after it. However its result is then written into `heroes`. To make it clear try this: `const embeddedResponse = this.http.get<EmbeddedResponse>(this.heroesUrl);
    const heroes = embeddedResponse.pipe(...);`

Comment: Ah I see. I always thought of it as a 'bubble'-behaviour. Is this true for any kind of nested functions? Thanks for your great help there :)

Comment: This is true for all **chained** functions. You can see that it is chained, but not nested when looking at the brackets of your `get`-call: `.pipe` gets called after the bracket for `get` is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catchError` operator should be inside pipe not inside `tap`

```
pipe(
    map((res: EmbeddedResponse) => res._embedded.heroes),
    tap(data => this.log('HeroService: fetched Heroes')),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
))
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kwx5xl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)